# How do i export all the data in civicrm?

Tags: export

I need to export all data in the database, activities, relationships, contacts everything. Is there a way to export all data? There is more room for human error if i have to do it individually by section on civi as how will i know if it downloaded all the fields?

Answer (score 1):

The way to export the complete data is a full database dump, eg via `mysqldump`.

Much of the data will be exported if you do it piece by piece, but it will not be complete and as you suggest there is risk of missing some fields doing so manually.

It's possible your hosting environment will offer some interface to make a db dump - they should have documentation, or you can ask their support staff.

If possible, I'd recommend talking to a technical advisor to ensure you get a complete copy. One you have this, make sure you verify it's complete somehow (ie by loading it into a new system); an untested backup shouldn't be trusted on faith alone.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how you use mysqldump?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure he does. Here's some documentation for you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html
But I also wonder if this is what you really-really want - the dump is limited in it's usefulness, mostly useful for moving an install, backing it up, or a really detailed migration to a different system.

Comment: It will be used for a detailed migration to a different system. Thank you!